# Resources folder is not accessible in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have created an application in MVC 3 and added a folder  [Resources].
Folder contains .resx files. But when i used .resx file in view there was no intellisense
and compiler threw an error =>

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Resources' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp.web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

i was using it in view =>  `<h1>@MyApp.web.Resources.Index.Heading</h1>`

index= Resx file Name, Heading=KeyName

Answer (score 2):

Resource type must be public (Access modifier option set to **public**)